# Emacs: how to auto-pick the next instead of previous window (pane) on C-x 0

Tags: emacs

Suppose I have an Emacs frame (what normal people call a window) with three windows (what normal people call panes or frames), and that it looks like this, with the cursor at `X`:

```
+-----------------------------------+ (original state)
| EMACS                             |
+-----------------+-----------------+
| a               | b     X         |
|                 +-----------------+
|                 | c               |
+-----------------+-----------------+
```

If I type `C-x 0`, Emacs will close the `b` window, and the cursor will be placed in the `a` window, like this:

```
+-----------------------------------+ (current result after C-x 0)
| EMACS                             |
+-----------------+-----------------+
| a               | c               |
|                 |                 |
|           X     |                 |
+-----------------+-----------------+
```

How can I configure Emacs to instead choose the *next* window instead of the *previous* window, e.g.

```
+-----------------------------------+ (desired result after C-x 0)
| EMACS                             |
+-----------------+-----------------+
| a               | c               |
|                 |    X            |
|                 |                 |
+-----------------+-----------------+
```

?

Comment: How about?:  First move to the window you want to be in and then either `(delete-window (previous-window))` or `(delete-window (next-window))`.  The optional window argument can be any window on the selected-frame.  Alternatively, a custom function can be created that modifies the default behavior of `delete-window` -- e.g., add a prefix-argument to the custom function that would trigger the desired behavior.  You can also define the target window like this:  `(window-in-direction 'right)`;  `(window-in-direction 'left)`;  `(window-in-direction 'above)`;  `(window-in-direction 'below)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @lawlist's comment, here's what I'm using now.

```
(defun delete-window-then-next ()
  ; Makes this bindable to global-set-key
  (interactive)
  ; delete the current window, moving to the previous
  (delete-window)
  ; go to the next now
  (other-window 1))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x o") 'delete-window-then-next)
```